# Resolve dependency errors while installing libmotif

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, dpkg, dependencies

I have a requirement where I need to bundle all the `*.deb` files required to install the `libmotif-dev` library along with the software package. This is because , the target computer where the software is being installed may not have an internet connection in order to run `apt-get` to install `libmotif-dev`. 
So the installation program first installs the "`libmotif-dev`" first by installing the deb files using `dpkg`. Then the software is installed.

Now the problem here is if the target Ubuntu computer is updated before my software in installed, then this could lead to some potential dependency errors.

```
Setting up libmpx2:amd64 (8-20180414-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpng-dev:amd64:
 libpng-dev:amd64 depends on libpng16-16 (= 1.6.34-1); however:
  Version of libpng16-16:amd64 on system is 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1.

dpkg: error processing package libpng-dev:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpng-tools:
 libpng-tools depends on libpng16-16 (= 1.6.34-1); however:
  Version of libpng16-16:amd64 on system is 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1.

dpkg: error processing package libpng-tools (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

In the above case,`libpng-dev` is looking for `libpng16-16` version 1.6.34-1, but since Ubuntu has been already updated, it now has `libpng16-16` version 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1. 
How can we resolve these kinds of problems?

I considered the possibility of purging the `libpng16-11.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1` file and then installing the 1.6.34-1 version.

However the problem is my installation bundle does not have the 1.6.34-1 version. The computer may not also have internet connection, so the old version cannot even be installed using `apt-get`.

Please advise how these type of dependency issues can be resolved. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably the "right" way to do this nowadays is to containerize your software + all its dependencies as a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. again would this not require an internet connection to install? The problem is that there is no network connection on the target computer.

Answer (score 2):

After much research, I finally decided to create a custom Ubuntu ISO with all the libraries required pre-installed on the ISO, using Cubic.

This way , the user could just install the new ISO and all the libraries , software would be pre-installed . This would not bring up any more dependency issues.